# Changing deep parts of expression specified by complex query

Tags: filtering, associations, coding-style

```
asso = <|"x" -> {
    <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
    <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}
|>
```

I want to find `"x"` value's element where `"c"` value is `{}` and modify its `"b"` value by applying `Framed` to it.

```
asso // Query["x", Select[#c === {} &], Framed@*"b"]
```

> ```
> {Framed["z"]}
> ```

But what I want to either return a full `asso` together with the result or to modify it in place.

I can rewrite the `Query`:

```
asso // Query[
  {"x"},
  MapAt[
    MapAt[Framed, #, "b"] &,
    #,
    Position[#, _?(Function[asso, asso["c"] === {}])]] &
  ]
```

> ```
> <|"x" -> {
>  <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>, 
>  <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> Framed["z"], "c" -> {}|>}
> |>
> ```

But it will quickly become unreadable for more complicated cases.

What is a generic approach to this problem?

When I need to approach it I just write a `Module`:

```
bSel = MapAt[Framed, #, "b"] &;
cPos = Position[#, _?(#c === {} &)] &
cSel = MapAt[bSel, #, cPos[#]] &
cSel /@ asso
```

to make it more maintainable. It requires more effort though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use a deferred subquery:

```
asso // Query[{"x"}, All, Query[If[#c === {}, {"b" -> Framed}, All]][#]&]
```

[image: result screenshot]

The inner subqueries are computed from the value of the `"c"` key of each inner association.  This is reasonably pleasant notationally, but it comes at the cost of multiple query compilations.  Compilation results are cached, so this overhead should not be significant unless the computed subqueries are truly different each time (unlike the present simple example which uses only two distinct subquery forms).

**Deeper Associations**

As noted in a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163892/changing-deep-parts-of-expression-based-on-complex-query/163909#comment434028_163909), the use of `Query` in this way becomes unworkable for deeper assocations.  Consider:

```
asso2 =
  <| "x" ->
       { <| "a" -> 5
          , "b" -> "y"
          , "c" -> {5, 6, 7}
          |>
       , <| "a" -> 6
          , "b" -> <| "x" ->
                        { <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>
                        , <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>
                        }
                    |>
          , "c" -> {}
          |>
       }
   |>
```

What if we want to apply `Frame` to the innermost `"b"` provided *both* the outer and inner values for `"c"` were `{}`?

The deferred subquery approach "works", but is an unreadable mess:

```
asso2 //
  Query[{"x"},All,Query[If[#c==={},Query[{"b"->Query[{"x"},All,Query[If[#c==={},{"b"->Framed},All]][#]&]}][#]&,All]][#]&]
```

[image: result of unreadable mess]

For this transformation, `ReplacePart` can do (a little?) better:

```
ReplacePart[
  asso2
, ii:{"x", i_, "b", "x", j_, "b"}
    /; asso2[["x", i, "c"]] === {}
    && asso2[["x", i, "b", "x", j, "c"]] === {}
    :> RuleCondition@Extract[asso2, ii, Framed]
]
```

[image: result of not-quite-as-unreadable mess]

... if we ignore the weird-looking `RuleCondition@Extract[...]` at the end.  That cryptic recipe is necessary to work-around the held evaluations within associations.  If we replace `RuleCondition@...` with the simpler `Framed[asso2[[ii]]]` then we get problematic output:

[image: problematic output]

Beware that even the `RuleCondition` trick has limitations -- it will not fully evaluate compound function expressions.

Comment: I feel your pain.  I am not aware of a general solution to this problem using just `Query`.  See my update for an alternative using `ReplacePart`.

Comment: @WReach thanks for the update. To be clear, I don't need Query at the end, it is only to show the query to be performed.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a recursive deferred sub-query.

```
drill[row_] :=
 Query[
   {"x"},
   All,
   Which[
     #["c"] != {}, #
     , Head@#["b"] === Association, Query[{"b" -> drill}]@#
     , True, Query[{"b" -> Framed}]@#
     ] &
   ]@row
```

Then

```
drill@asso
drill@asso2 (* from WReach post *)
```

return as expected.

This is particular to this particular structure.  However, it can be generalised by adding commands for each level of the nested association should the structure and/or conditions change down the levels.

```
ClearAll[seekReplace]
seekReplace[row_, {}] := row
seekReplace[row_, cmd_?(VectorQ[#, AssociationQ] &)] :=
 Query[
   {"x"},
   All,
   Which[
     First[cmd]["ExitSeek"]@#, #
     , First[cmd]["Seek"]@#, 
     Query[{First[cmd]["SeekKey"] -> (seekReplace[#, Rest@cmd] &)}]@#
     , True, 
     Query[{First[cmd]["ReplaceKey"] -> First[cmd]["Replace"]}]@#
     ] &
   ]@row
```

Here the commands are the same since the structure and conditions are the same at each level.

```
seekCommands = <|
   "ExitSeek" -> (#["c"] != {} &), 
   "Seek" -> (Head@#["b"] === Association &), "SeekKey" -> "b", 
   "Replace" -> Framed, "ReplaceKey" -> "b"|>;
seekCommands = ConstantArray[seekCommands, 2]
```

Then the following return as expected.

```
seekReplace[asso, seekCommands]
seekReplace[asso2, seekCommands]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
asso = <|"x" -> {<|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>, <|
     "a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}|>

targetpos = 
 Most /@ Select[Position[asso, {}], MatchQ[#, {__, Key["c"]}] &]

MapAt[Query[{"b" -> Framed}], asso, targetpos]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Isn't `Riffle[Key /@ searchKeys, __Integer]` too optimistic in general? :)

Comment: I'm not sure yet, need to test, but isn't `Riffle[Key /@ searchKeys, __Integer]` likely to find false matches? Will see, p.s. you are assuming that we know the value of the target, but that is not the case in  my example.

Comment: Sorry for a delay. There is a filter based on `{}` value in my example but at the end I apply `Framed` to a particular `"b"` key, which has `"z"` value in this case but it is now known up front.

Comment: @Kuba Sorry, i completely misread your post. See my edit. Not very elegant but short and does it job.